# How can I make text inside set notation look like normal text?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, formatting

I'm very new to LaTeX, and have never been very good with computers, so apologies for not knowing how to post questions on here properly or missing out anything important.

I have this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[F_f=\{z\in \mathbb{\hat{C}}:(\vert f^n(z) \vert) is bounded\}\]
\end{document}
```

"is bounded" comes out in italics and I'd like it to look like normal text (as in text not in `$$` or `\[\]` signs. Any help would be appreciated.

And I realize that I've got lots of `\` signs missing, they don't seem to show up.

Comment: Use: `\text{ is bounded}`.

Comment: Use `\text{ is bounded}` and be happy.

Comment: Better yet, `\{z\in\hat{\mathbb{C}}:\text{$(\lvert f^n(z)\rvert)$ is bounded}\}`

Comment: @egreg You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not fond of long set descriptions like this, so I'll show also how I'd describe the set.

The trick is to temporarily go in text mode. However the input

```
(\lvert f^n(z) \rvert) \text{ is bounded}\}
```

is awkward and I find it much better to use `\text` for the whole description, getting back in math mode inside it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
Define
\[
F_{f}=\{z\in \hat{\mathbb{C}}:
  \text{$(\lvert f^n(z) \rvert)$ is bounded}\}
\]
and prove something about this.

We define $F_{f}$ as the set of $z\in\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ such that the 
sequence $(\lvert f^n(z) \rvert)$ is bounded.
\end{document}
```

Note that the correct syntax is `\hat{\mathbb{C}}` and it would be meaningful to have something like

```
\newcommand{\numberset}[1]{\mathbb{#1}}
\newcommand{\nC}{\numberset{C}}
\newcommand{\hnC}{\hat{\nC}}
```

so we can write `z\in\hnC` and don't bother with formatting instructions in the document body.

Note also that `\lvert...\rvert` is the correct usage when `amsmath` is loaded.

[image]

Comment: Now that you are at it, I think it would also be great `\DeclarePairedDelimiter\set{\lbrace}{\rbrace}` and `\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}` and use them appropriately.

Comment: @Manuel I don't agree about `\set`; for `\abs` it could be. However it's outside the scope of the question.

Comment: @egreg Is there a particular reason for writing, say, `\[\text{$f$ is}\]` instead of `\[f\text{ is}\]`? (Personally I like your way of doing is, so I'm just curious.)

Comment: @SvendTveskæg I find it awkward to have `f\text{ is...}`: `\text{$f$ is...}` is clearer and there's no risk of forgetting spaces. The clause is the complete `$f$ is...`.

Comment: Thanks, egreg. There is no difference in the output, right?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Under normal settings, no.

Comment: @Manuel, see the latest mathtools manual. If I remember correctly I did add an example on how to make `\Set` with a build in feature for scaling `|` (if used). I use that construction all the time in what ever I edit. Then the set builder symbol is independent of the syntax being used.